# How do I change initial width of the the button before toggle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Need help how to make the width of the Chat button on this [demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/uCaho) shorter when not clicked? :( Been trying to figure it out but no luck .

JS

```
function showChat() {
    jQuery("#blk-collaboration .chatbox").slideToggle("slow",function(){
        jQuery("#blk-collaboration #toggle").css("background","#45A1F1");
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.chatbox').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Let

```
<div id="btn-chat" class="button wide">Button</div>
```

is your button.

Style for button let be

```
.wide {  

background: black; 
  height: 100px; 
  width:  600px !important; /* Width of wide button */ 
}
.button {
  background: black; 
  height: 100px; 
  width: 250px; /*Width of regular button */ 
}
```

And jquery code to change button width cat look as

```
//Add click handler to button.
jQuery('#btn-chat').click(function() {
  $(this)//this is a button DOM element. wrapping in jQuery object.
  .toggleClass('wide'); // toggling .wide class ( if class presend it will removed, if not - added ) .
});
```

Comment: This didn't work :( Can you show it on my demo? :( @nazarevic

Comment: It never goes back to its original width :(

Comment: so, you want your button after first click became shorter and after secord click wider againe?

Comment: YES! Absolutely! Please look at http://codepen.io/anon/pen/uCaho When the window maximize, the blue header/button widens... then when clicked again to hide the iframe on that example, the button/header shortens .

Answer (score 0):

Set the initial width in the stylesheet,  then again the full with a on click event by adding a new class via. addClass.

Comment: SORRY i'm REALLY a beginner with Jquery. could you provide a sample please?